# Swapping 2 continuous strings - time complexity

Tags: c, time-complexity, c-strings

Goal: Function, that takes a pointer to string and two lengths, and swaps between the inside strings represented by the lengths **without** using additional memory that depends on the size of the input.
For example, given the string "abcdef123" and lengths 6,3 the result should be "123abcdef".

One possible recursive implementation (mine) is:

```
void invertStrings(char* str, int len1, int len2){
    if(len1==0 || len2==0)
        return;
    if(len1>len2){
        for(int i=0;i<len2;++i)
            swapChars(str, len1+i, len1-len2+i);
        invertStrings(str,len1-len2,len2);
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0;i<len1;++i)
            swapChars(str, len1+i, i);
        invertStrings(str+len1,len1,len2-len1);
    }
}
```

I think that the time complexity is O(len1+len2) or maybe even something like O(max{len1,len2}).

Question: what is the time complexity and how could it be proven?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the function `sw`?

Comment: I would call this an in-place rotation. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/ and replace "ForwardIterator" with "char*" in your head. Keep in mind that "last" is exclusive.

Comment: @user295691: Sorry, this is a swap between two chars in the string. Fixed.

Comment: @sellibitze: Good reference. But, I i think while the complexity of it is O(n), it has some overhaed since every element is being swapped many times, and in my implementation most elements being swapped only once. In worst case (when len1 or len2 in 1) this would be very the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm as written appears to be `O(len1+len2)`.  Let's define the "total work" of a function invocation as `len1 + len2`.  Each time the function is called, it does `min(len1,len2)` swaps, and recursively invokes itself with `total_work[n+1] = total_work[n] - min(len1,len2)`.  So an upper bound on the work done in all recursive invocations is just `len1+len2`.

The additional twist here is that the termination condition depends on `gcd(len1,len2)`.  The loop terminates when one of len1,len2 are 0, so we're guaranteed that the number of swaps is strictly less than `len1+len2`.  How much is "left over" at the end depends on the gcd of the two lengths.  As an example, if we have `(6,3)` as the starting point, then we'll get `(6,3)->(3,3)->(0,3)`, for a total of 6 swaps (less than the 8 expected).  But if we start with `(7,3)->(4,3)->(1,3)->(1,2)->(1,1)->(1,0)` we end up doing 9 swaps.  The number of swaps in general is exactly `len1 + len2 - gcd(len1,len2)`.

Comment: Yes, `n == len1+len2`. I will amend.

Comment: 1)Is it an induction proof?

Comment: It is not an induction proof; I would call it a direct proof (at least the first part).  The second part (the gcd part) I stated without proof, but it follows pretty directly from the proof of Euclid's algorithm for computing the gcd.

Comment: For generally analyzing running time of algorithms, you would use the so-called "Master Theorem"; in this case I cheated because the algorithm only uses tail recursion, so can be trivially transformed to an iterative solution, which is much easier to analyze.

Comment: Based on what you said I'd offer an formal inductive proof. The recursive formula is:
T[len1+len2]=T[len1+len2-min{len1,len2}]+O(min{len1,len2})
T[1]=O[1].

Base case is easy.
Lets assume for n and proof for n+1:
T[len1+len2+1]
=T[len1+len2+1-(min{len1+1,len2+1})]+O(min{len1+1,len2+1})=<
T[len1+len2]+O(min{...})=
O(len1+len2)+O(min{...})=
O(len1+len2). 
What do you think?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21965/discussion-between-user295691-and-sanich)

Answer (score 0):

It's **O(n)**, because every swap operation puts at least one of the characters in it's correct final position.

Algorithmic complexity is a function of the size of the input and here the cost of the operation grows linearly with the size of the input.

Typically with complexity, you care only about the type of growth it exhibits.  If it's linear, you don't care what the coefficient is (e.g., you don't care if it's two times the amount of input data or 7).

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot that it should be implemented without additional memory. Edition made.

Comment: Oh, that makes quite a difference.

Comment: Would you please explain what do you mean by "order statements"?

Comment: It's a poor wording, I mean when people say O(n) or O(n^2) or O(nlogn)

Comment: It's not "order", it's "ordo", but that's just the name of the Greek letter. The property itself is called "algorithmic complexity" or "time complexity" or "computational complexity".